# create object dynamically of all db context EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, unit-testing

How to create object of all db context table dynamically. Following is the code i have tried till now and stuck.

```
 PB_Pan_DvContext obj = new PB_Pan_DvContext();    
 var metadata = ((IObjectContextAdapter)obj).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;    
 var tables = metadata.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.SSpace)
          .GetItems<EntityContainer>()
          .Single()
          .BaseEntitySets
          .OfType<EntitySet>()
          .Where(s => !s.MetadataProperties.Contains("Type")
            || s.MetadataProperties["Type"].ToString() == "Tables");    
                    foreach (var table in tables)
                    {
                        var tableName = table.MetadataProperties.Contains("Table")
                        && table.MetadataProperties["Table"].Value != null
                        ? table.MetadataProperties["Table"].Value.ToString()
                        : table.Name;
                        var tableSchema = table.MetadataProperties["Schema"].Value.ToString();
                        // here i want to create dynamic object of table   
                    }
```

Any clues on how to implement this? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you on about? What is `tables` it doesn't help you used 'var' to declare it. What does it have to do with `unit-testing`?

Comment: @Aron     
 
tables is list of all tables in PB_Pan_DvContext

Comment: Erm... what is the type? What do you intend to use it for?